# Reference request: large generalized probability measures

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

I'm interested in references relevant to the following: what is the right generalization, if there is one, of a probability measure that takes on values in an structure of more than continuum size?

I'm thinking of something like the following: let $F$ be an ordered field, let $F_+$ be the nonnegative elements of $F$, and let $\phantom{}^\omega F$ be the set of infinite sequences of elements of $F$. We say that a partial function $\sigma: \phantom{}^\omega F \rightharpoonup F$ is a summability notion for $F$ if (1) it extends finite sums in the obvious way: whenever only finitely many members of $\vec{a} \in \phantom{}^\omega F$ are nonzero, $\sigma(\vec{a})= \sum_{\{ i \in \omega: a_i \neq 0 \}} a_i$ and (2) it has an appropriate order-independence property for positive partial sums: if $a_i \in F_+$ for all $i \in \omega$, then  if $\sigma(\vec{a})$ exists and $\vec{b}$ is a permutation of $\vec{a}$, then $\sigma(\vec{a}) = \sigma(\vec{b})$. (There are probably other properties we would want, but I leave this open for the moment.)

We can then come up with a generalized version of the Kolmogorov axioms: given a set $\Omega$, a $\sigma$-algebra $A$ over $\Omega$, and an ordered field $F$ equipped with a summability notion (which we can just write $\sum$), we say that an $f: A \times A \rightarrow F_+$ is a generalized probability measure if $f(\Omega) = 1$ and $f(\bigcup X)=\sum \{ f(x): x \in X \}$ for $X$ a countable pairwise disjoint collection of elements of $A$. The advantage of using a formal sum, rather than a standard notion of convergence, is that it can make sense even when there are no nontrivial converging sequences in the natural topology on $F$ (as will be the case, e.g., when $F$ is larger than continuum size, as there will generally be no countable dense subsets).

I can't help thinking that this must be well-trodden ground, but I can't find any references that are exactly on point. The closest thing is the generalization of metric spaces by Ralph Kopperman ("All Topologies Come From Generalized Metrics", American Mathematical Monthly 95 (1988): 89--97, doi:10.1080/00029890.1988.11971974); I suppose I'm seeking something similar for measure theory. Any pointers to sources would be much appreciated.

Comment: Addressing the issues mentioned in the first paragraph, there is a very extensive (and easy to locate) literature on measures with values in Banach spaces (even lcs's and tvs's), particularly their connections with the geometric theory  (Radon-Nikodym property).  In order to incorporate the concept of a probability measure, you require more structure, in this case typically that of a Banach lattice with unit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the *right* generalization but here is an article on [Non-Archimedean probability](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00032-012-0191-x) by Benci et al (Milan J. Math. 81 (2013), no. 1, 121–151).
The version of the real line used there is of inaccessible cardinality.